# Where are upower's icon-names defined?

Tags: icons, freedesktop, battery

When I run `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice` (may be different on different machines, get a list with `upower --enumerate`), I get output similar to this:

```
power supply:         yes
updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 AM CET (1444049000 seconds ago)
has history:          no
has statistics:       no
battery
  present:             yes
  state:               discharging
  warning-level:       none
  energy:              47.716 Wh
  energy-full:         47.716 Wh
  energy-rate:         4.048 W
  time to empty:       11.8 hours
  percentage:          100%
  icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
```

I'm wondering where the `icon-name`s are defined. Is there a list with all possible `battery-*` icons?

I found http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html, but it only lists `battery-caution` and `battery-low`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find full list of avaialable values for icon-name in upower source code.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/upower/tree/src/up-device.c#n99

- ac-adapter-symbolic
- battery-missing-symbolic
- battery-empty-symbolic
- battery-full-charged-symbolic
- battery-caution-charging-symbolic
- battery-caution-symbolic
- battery-low-charging-symbolic
- battery-low-symbolic
- battery-good-charging-symbolic
- battery-good-symbolic
- battery-full-charging-symbolic
- battery-full-symbolic

And XDG Icon Naming Specification is not related to them.